# Browser can't process the code, how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i've been trying to take an array and use it to find the largest area in it (using array as height and length between array variables as width) but when i try to launch it the page simply won't load, how can i fix it?

```
var array = [1, 8, 6, 2, 5, 4, 8, 3, 7];
```

var height, width, area;
var maxArea = 0;

function largestArea () {

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

    for (n = i+1; n = array.length - 2; n++) {

        if (array[i] > array[n]) {
            height = array[n];
        }
        else if (array[i] = array[n]) {
            height = array[n];
        }
        else {
            height = array[i];
        }

        width = n - i;
        area = height * width;

        if (area > maxArea) {
            maxArea = area;
        }
    }
}

console.log(maxArea);
```

}

largestArea();

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue may be because you accidentally assigned `n` twice instead of using comparison as I think is want you really wanted:

`for (n = i+1; n = array.length - 2; n++) {`

Comment: thanks! completely missed that!

Comment:  If it worked you can mark the answer as solved using the v mark